# Equation of motion for a beam subject to harmonic force. What will be the mass of the beam in this question?

Tags: harmonic-functions, classical-mechanics

This is a pretty straightforward question. I was able to use Rayleigh's method to get the equation of motion for the beam and mass on it. However, I cannot understand how you can possibly calculate the mass of the beam without knowing the density. Here is the question:

[actual question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMwEU.png)

And here is how they solved it in the solution manual. Please ignore everything else and look at the part highlighted in red. What exactly are they multiplying the volume of the beam with?

[how they did it in the solution manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaap9.png)

Comment: density of steel ?

Comment: I think the result in the second bracket represents density of steel which ranges from 7480 to 8000 kg/cu. m.

Comment: the density of steel is not mentioned in the question. So, I assume this information will be provided in the question